# How to detect hovering over a static Win32 control?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having trouble detecting a hover over a static Win32 control.

This is not a duplicate issue because this looks for multiple static controls instead of just looking for a single known handle to a static control at compile time.

While this can be done in seconds in another language, I'm growing a little frustrated after trying things out for some hours. I hope to get an answer here.

First, I created a class called Label. I create a static control window within it. I'll refer to static as label for now on.

```
// Create the label's handle.
m_handle = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "static", m_text.c_str(),
    WS_CHILD | SS_LEFT | SS_NOTIFY, m_x, m_y, m_width, m_height,
    m_parentWindow, (HMENU)(UINT_PTR)m_id, m_hInstance, NULL);
if (m_handle == NULL)
    return false;
```

When the mouse hovers over this label, the following method should be called:

```
void Label::invokeOnMouseHover()
{
    if (m_onMouseOver)
        m_onMouseOver();
}
```

This will call my method:

```
void lblName_onMouseOver()
{
    MessageBox::show("Hovering!", "My Console",
        MessageBoxButtons::Ok, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
}
```

This is how I create it from the top level:

```
Label lblName("This is a label.", 0, 0);
lblName.setVisible(true);
lblName.OnMouseOver(lblName_onMouseOver); 
frm.add(lblName);
```

Admit it, this thin layer is beautiful.

While my callbacks are working fine for my Button and Checkbox controls, I noticed that statics are a little different.

So, let's go down a few levels:

This is in the main window's procedure:

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{  
    int xPos = LOWORD(lParam);
    int yPos = HIWORD(lParam);

    frm.setMousePos(xPos, yPos);  

    // Get the static's id
    int id = // ?? Which static control id is it out of several?

                // Obtain the control associated with the id.
        X3D::Windows::Control *ctrl = frm.getControls().find(id)->second;
    if (ctrl == NULL)
        return 0;

    // Check if this is a X3D Label control.
    if (typeid(*ctrl) == typeid(X3D::Windows::Label))
    {
        Label *lbl = dynamic_cast<X3D::Windows::Label*>(ctrl);

        int xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        int yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

        if (xPos >= lbl->getX() &&
            yPos >= lbl->getY() &&
            (xPos < (lbl->getX() + lbl->getWidth())) &&
            (yPos < (lbl->getY() + lbl->getHeight())))
        {
            if (lbl != NULL)
                lbl->invokeOnMouseHover();
        }
    }
}
break;
```

What I'm trying to do here is detect what label id was detected, and then call Label::invokeOnMouseOver().

Even though I Understand I need to use TRACKMOUSEEVENT at some point, its field member 'HWND' requires the label's handle. But I can't easily say which handle it will be because the collection may contain one or several labels.

Overall, I'm looking for suggestions on how to either restructure this or see if there's an easy solution here. My guess is I'm overthinking this.

Thanks.

**Update:**

Here is a code update after reading the first answer with the first solution. While this solves the hover issue, I don't see the label's text on execution.

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{  
    int xPos = LOWORD(lParam);
    int yPos = HIWORD(lParam);

    // Get the mouse position
    frm.setMousePos(xPos, yPos);  

    // Check for labels
    X3D::Windows::Control *ctrl = (X3D::Windows::Control*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

    if (ctrl)
    {
        // Check if this is a X3D Label control.
        Label *lbl = dynamic_cast<X3D::Windows::Label*>(ctrl);
        if (lbl)
            lbl->invokeOnMouseHover();

        return CallWindowProc(lbl->getOldProc(), hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    } 
}
break;
```

And the control creation:

```
// Create the label's handle.
m_handle = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TEXT("static"), m_text.c_str(),
    WS_CHILD | SS_LEFT | SS_NOTIFY, m_x, m_y, m_width, m_height,
    m_parentWindow, (HMENU)(UINT_PTR)m_id, m_hInstance, NULL);
if (!m_handle)
    return false;

SetWindowLongPtr(m_handle, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)(X3D::Windows::Control*)this);
m_oldProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(m_handle, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&wndProc);
```

If it's a paint issue, this is what I have in WndProc.

```
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        return 0;
    }
    break;
```

**Update #2:**

The alternative solution fixed the issue.

If anyone has trouble with unresolved external symbols with SetWindowSubclass() in the future, remember to add the following to your project or just #pragma it:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
```

Comment: I noticed an odd and related behavior: When my mouse is over the label, WM_MOUSEMOVE isn't called. When I move the mouse outside of the label and onto the main window, WM_MOUSEMOVE is called.

Comment: There were some helpful comments here, but I don't see them anymore. Not sure why.

Comment: I deleted them because I'm in the process of moving them into an answer...

Comment: _Admit it, this thin layer is beautiful._ Not really, sorry.  Too many `dynamic_cast`s for my liking.  Why do you need all those?

Comment: @Bob I posted an answer which should help you with your ongoing efforts to build this beast (you're going in the wrong direction at the moment, those `dynamic_casts`s will skin you alive), please see below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only identifying info that `WM_MOUSEMOVE` gives you is the `HWND` that the mouse is moving over (or the `HWND` that has [captured the mouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcapture)).  The reported X/Y coordinates are relative to that `HWND`.  That is the `HWND` that you are looking for, so you don't need to hunt for it, the message gives it to you.

If you need access to an `HWND`'s control ID, you can use [`GetDlgCtrlID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgctrlid) for that.  But note that every `HWND` has **its own** window procedure, so control IDs are typically only useful for notification messages, like `WM_COMMAND` and `WM_NOTIFY`, which are sent to a control's parent window (and even then, such notifications also carry the child's `HWND` as well).

When the mouse moves over a particular `HWND`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is posted to the message procedure of *that* `HWND` only (or to the `HWND` that has captured the mouse).  It sounds like you are expecting it to be posted to the control's *parent* window instead, and that is simply not the case.  That is why your `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler is not being called.  You are handling the message at the wrong level.  You need to be prepared to handle messages on a per-control basis instead, using the control's own message procedure.

It would be more efficient to store your `Control` object's `this` pointer inside its associated `HWND` itself, via `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_USERDATA)`, `SetWindowSubClass()`, or `SetProp()`, and then your message handlers can access the `Control*` pointer of the message's reported `HWND` when needed, for example:

```
// Create the label's handle.
m_handle = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TEXT("static"), m_text.c_str(),
    WS_CHILD | SS_LEFT | SS_NOTIFY, m_x, m_y, m_width, m_height,
    m_parentWindow, (HMENU)(UINT_PTR)m_id, m_hInstance, NULL);
if (!m_handle)
    return false;
SetWindowLongPtr(m_handle, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)(X3D::Windows::Control*)this);
m_oldproc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(m_handle, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&MyWndProc);

...

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            ...

            X3D::Windows::Control *ctrl = (X3D::Windows::Control*) GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
            if (ctrl)
            {
                // Check if this is a X3D Label control.
                Label *lbl = dynamic_cast<X3D::Windows::Label*>(ctrl);
                if (lbl)
                    lbl->invokeOnMouseHover();
            }

            break;
        }

        ...
    }

    return CallWindowProc(m_oldproc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
// Create the label's handle.
m_handle = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TEXT("static"), m_text.c_str(),
    WS_CHILD | SS_LEFT | SS_NOTIFY, m_x, m_y, m_width, m_height,
    m_parentWindow, (HMENU)(UINT_PTR)m_id, m_hInstance, NULL);
if (!m_handle)
    return false;
SetWindowSubclass(m_handle, &MySubclassProc, 1, (DWORD_PTR)(X3D::Windows::Control*)this);

...

LRESULT CALLBACK MySubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, &MySubclassProc, uIdSubclass);
            break;

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            X3D::Windows::Control *ctrl = (X3D::Windows::Control*) dwRefData;

            // Check if this is a X3D Label control.
            Label *lbl = dynamic_cast<X3D::Windows::Label*>(ctrl);
            if (lbl)
                lbl->invokeOnMouseHover();

            break;
        }

        ...
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: GWL_USERDATA is undefined in my x64 project. GWLP_USERDATA is suggested here, if I'm understanding correctly: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c62b1bf5-6a03-4c66-b24b-ea9fec3f2695/error-c2065-gwluserdata-undeclared-identifier?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: Please see my current code above and the paint issue (text not visible for some reason).

Comment: @Bob: The `SetWindowSubclass` is so far superior, don't even worry about getting the parameters right for the `SetWindowLongPtr` approach

Comment: So go for the second? I'll try it out.

Comment: @Bob: Also note that your parent window's WndProc is not suitable for subclassing the label.  The one should call `DefWindowProc` for unhandled messages, the other should pass everything through to `DefSubclassProc`.  Failure to forward `WM_PAINT` to the original window procedure for `STATIC` windows is the reason your labels no longer render.

Comment: All in all a great answer, just wanted to point out a slight error that can be fixed to make it better :) *"note that every HWND has its own window procedure"* is wrong, the window procedure is per window class, not per window.

Comment: @JohannGerell except when you subclass, which you usually need to do when using "standard" classes, then it is per-window

Comment: @RemyLebeau True that :)

Answer (score 0):

This post doesn't answer the question you asked but you should read it.  It is important, and it is posted in a spirit of helpfulness after my rather acid comment above.  I hope you find it so.

This class library is going to run into trouble.  Code like this (using a `dynamic_cast`):

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    X3D::Windows::Control *ctrl = (X3D::Windows::Control*) dwRefData;

    // Check if this is a X3D Label control.
    Label *lbl = dynamic_cast<X3D::Windows::Label*>(ctrl);
    if (lbl)
        lbl->invokeOnMouseHover();

    break;
}
```

Is almost always wrong.

Why?  Well, suppose you want to hover over some other kind of control?  What are you going to do now?  And these guys are just going to multiply like rabbits, so don't do that.

Instead, for a message that the library understands (such as this one), declare a corresponding **virtual** method in the base class that derived classes can override if they're interested in processing that message.  *Then* you have the basis of a solid design (and this is pretty basic stuff).

So, in this case you would have:

```
class Control                  // Base class
{
    ...
    virtual void onMouseHover (...) { }
    ...
};
```

And then:

```
class Label : public Control   // Derived class
{
    ...
    virtual void onMouseHover (...) override { ...  }
    ...
};
```

Now for my second point: you are going to find that, particularly for dialogs, your application is going to want to handle a lot of messages that the base class doesn't understand (or care about).

How are you going to do this?  Are you going to add code to the base class for each new message that your application (or for that matter specific types of control implemented in the class library) becomes interested in?  That is not a very attractive prospect.

Now MFC handles this with something it calls a [message map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x0cx6b1.aspx), which is essentially a table of message ID's and their corresponding command handlers which you can associate with (in your case) any object ultimately derived from `Control` and I recommend you do something similar.

But thanks to the magic of the STL, you can do better.  I have something like this in my class library (my base class is actually called `Window`, as I would suggest yours should be):

```
typedef INT_PTR (Window::*MESSAGE_HANDLER)
    (HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// Register a message handler
void Window::RegisterMessageHandler (UINT uMsg, MESSAGE_HANDLER handler);
```

And what `RegisterMessageHandler()` actually does is to add `handler` to a `std::unordered_map` associated with the `Window` object using `uMsg` as a key.  Then, when that message subsequently comes in, it can be dispatched to the right handler *without the base class knowing anything about the meaning of the message whatsoever*, and that's what you're going to need.

So, you might declare the following in class `Control` (code untested, written in Notepad):

```
class Control                  // Base class
{
    ...
    std::unordered_map <UINT, MESSAGE_HANDLER> m_message_map;
    ...
};
```

And then `RegisterMessageHandler()` might look like this:

```
void Window::RegisterMessageHandler (UINT uMsg, MESSAGE_HANDLER handler)
{
    m_message_map.emplace (uMsg, handler);
}
```

And `MySubclassProc()` might look like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MySubclassProc (HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    X3D::Windows::Control *ctrl = (X3D::Windows::Control*) dwRefData;
    auto handler ctrl->m_message_map.find (uMsg);
    if (handler != ctrl->m_message_map.end ())
        return handler.second (hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    ...
}
```

My own class library is actually more sophisticated than this (I started with something simple but then embellished it over time) but that's the basic idea.  You might have to master a few C++ skills to pull this off but trust me, if you implement something like this you'll be very glad you did, down the line.